# laravel installation got error

Tags: php, laravel

This error occurred in compiled.php line 7772:

```
at EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher('SomeRandomString', 'AES-256-CBC') in compiled.php line 7762
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in compiled.php line 1353
at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in compiled.php line 1309
```

Comment: please elaborate, how you were doing installation and when this error comes ?

Comment: Do you have the requierment (PHP version, etc..)?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And after that generate a new key for your application via

```
php artisan key:generate
```